# Cannot send multiple form data to routes in Node.js using req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, handlebars.js

I am trying to modify data in a database based off an administrator making changes to a table in a form. My problem is for the save button below I need to send five pieces of information to update: 
1. word
2. replacement
3. replacementMethod
4. active
5. id

I can do this easily if it were just one piece of data as the req.body object is allowed one key-value pair (name and value). In fact, I did this with the delete button and it works fine by sending the primary key and then deleting the row.

For the save button I thought the solution would be to just pass in the "this" object. However accessing any properties even in the router.post function shows up as undefined or I get { data: '[object Object]' } where I can't seem to access the object data. I have tried many many different ways and console.log printouts and searched the internet to no avail. Can someone show me the right way to do this? I've spent half a day on this and not gotten anywhere. Thank you.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Banned Word</th>
    <th>Replacement</th>
    <th>Replacement Method</th>
    <th>Active</th>
    <th>Remove Word</th>
    <th>Save Changes</th>
</tr>
{{#each bannedwords}}
<tr>
    <td contenteditable='true'>{{this.word}}</td>
    <td contenteditable='true'>{{this.replacement}}</td>

    {{#ifCond this.replacementMethod 0}}
        <td class='select'> 
            <select>        
                <option value="0" selected>Replacement</option>
                <option value="1">Stars</option>
                <option value="2">Grawlix</option>   
            </select>
        </td>
    {{/ifCond}}

    {{#ifCond this.replacementMethod 1}}
        <td class='select'> 
            <select>        
                <option value="0">Replacement</option>
                <option value="1" selected>Stars</option>
                <option value="2">Grawlix</option>   
            </select>
        </td>
    {{/ifCond}}

    {{#ifCond this.replacementMethod 2}}

    <td align='center' class='select'> 
            <select>        
                <option value="0">Replacement</option>
                <option value="1">Stars</option>
                <option value="2" selected>Grawlix</option>   
            </select>
    </td>
    {{/ifCond}}

    {{#if this.active includeZero=false}}
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="return true;" checked/></td>
    {{else}}
        <td><input type="checkbox" onclick="return true;" /></td>
    {{/if}}
    <td><button formmethod="POST" formaction="/deleteWord" type="Delete" name="word" value="{{this.word}}"  class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button></td>
    <td><button formmethod="POST" formaction="/modifyWord" type="Save" name="data" value="{{this}}" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button></td>
</tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>
```

In my routes index.js I have:

```
router.post('/modifyWord',isAdminMiddleware(), function(req, res, next){
modifyBannedWord(req);
res.redirect('/admin');
});
```

And finally:

```
function modifyBannedWord(req){
const db = require('../db.js');
var temp = req.body;
db.query('UPDATE from badwords set word = ?,  replacement = ?, replacementMethod = ?, active = ?  , WHERE id = ?' , [temp.data.word , temp.data.replacement, temp.data.replacementMethod, temp.data.active, temp.data.id], function(err, results){
});
}
```

As an aside, the modifyBannedWord function may not be correct (i.e var temp = req.body) . I've changed it so many times I can't remember which way it's suppose to be but nonetheless I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to name the select tags like this

```
<select name="somename"></select>
```

And in your route

```
var somevar = req.body.somename;
```